# How to pass a name-value pair as an argument in Perl

Tags: perl, string, escaping

I think this is very basic perl question but I am not getting it through.

I am using LWP::UserAgent package to build a post request in perl script.
The code is as follows:

```
my $urlStr = "http://localhost/testproj/AServlet";
my $postDataStr = "{name => \'ankur434\'}";
my $response = $ua->post($urlStr, $postDataStr);
```

The above code doesn't work & gives following error -

```
<Dec 6, 2010 3:15:54 PM IST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101215> <Malformed Request "/testproj/AServlet". Request parsing failed, Code: -1>
```

However when I directly pass postDataStr's value to post method, it works perfectly well, like shown below:

```
my $response = $ua->post($urlStr, {name => 'ankur434'});
```

I tried few options like escaping { with backward slash (\{) but nothing worked...

Can anyone suggest something? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{name => 'ankur434'}
```

is a hash reference.

```
"{name => \'ankur434\'}"
```

is, as your variable name indicates, a string.
Perl does not automatically convert the latter to the former.
You seem to be under the impression that in Perl, only strings can be assigned to variables or passed to subroutines.
This is not the case.  Just use

```
my $urlStr = "http://localhost/testproj/AServlet";
my $postData = {name => 'ankur434'};
my $response = $ua->post($urlStr, $postData);
```

Comment: Hi, I've another related question. I need to pass a string variable in hash reference. It's like: my $tempStr = ''; my $anotherTempStr = { $tempStr }; It doesn't work. What can I do? I am googling but not found any solution yet. Thanks.

Comment: Not to worry. I figured out. Following helped - sub foo
    {
        my $hash_ref;
     
        $hash_ref->{ 'key1' } = 'value1';
        $hash_ref->{ 'key2' } = 'value2';
        $hash_ref->{ 'key3' } = 'value3';
     
        return $hash_ref;
    }
     
    my $hash_ref = foo();

Comment: Nice, but you can also use `my $hash_ref = { 'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2'}` or even `my $hash_ref = { key1 => value1, key2 => value2}`.  For key and value you can of course use variables as well.